# How to force long double in Perl

Tags: perl, printf, precision, long-double

I lose precision when doing arithmetic or trying to print (debug) numbers this big:
1234567890.123456789

I think my problems are with $d (result of arithmetic) and the formatted print of $e.
How can I force long doubles? My Perl version (5.8.4 on SUN) says it's possible.
sprintf has a size option for long doubles (q or L or ll), but I haven't figured out how to use it, and don't know if it would work with printf.

**Edit:** I added BigFloat, which works! But I'd still like to force long doubles.

Try to add 1234567890 + 0.123456789
and subtract 1234567890 - 0.123456789.

```
use Config;
use Math::BigFloat;
$a = 1234567890;
$b = 123456789;
$c = $b/1e9;                   # 0.123456789
$d = $a + $c;                  # not enough precision (32-bit or double?)
$e = sprintf("%d.%.9d",$a,$b); # combine as strings
$f = 1234567890.123456789;     # for reference (not enough precision)

# Use BigFloat to bypass lack of longdbl
$aBig = Math::BigFloat->new("$a");
$dSum = $aBig->fadd("$c");         # $dSum = $a + $c
$aBig = Math::BigFloat->new("$a"); # <-- Need a new one for every operation?
$dDif = $aBig->fsub(abs("$c"));    # $dDif = $a - $c

print "a $a\n";             # 1234567890  
print "c $c\n";             # 0.123456789
print "d=a+c $d\n";         # 1234567890.12346  <-- **Problem**
print "dSum=a+c $dSum\n";   # 1234567890.123456789  <-- Solution
print "dDif=a-c $dDif\n";   # 1234567890.876543211  <-- Solution
print "e $e\n";             # 1234567890.123456789
print "f $f\n";             # 1234567890.12346  <-- double, 52-bit, not longdbl? 
printf ("printf    e 20.9f %20.9f\n",$e);    # 1234567890.123456717 <-- **Problem**
printf ("printf dSum 20.9f %20.9f\n",$dSum); # 1234567890.123456717 <-- **Problem**
printf ("printf dSum 20s %20s\n",$dSum);     # 1234567890.123456789 
printf ("printf dDif 20.9f %20.9f\n",$dDif); # 1234567890.876543283 <-- **Problem**
printf ("printf dDif 20s %20s\n",$dDif);     # 1234567890.876543211 

print "uselongdouble $Config{uselongdouble}\n"; # empty. No long doubles by default
print "d_longdbl $Config{d_longdbl}\n";         # "define". Supports long doubles
print "size double longdbl $Config{doublesize} $Config{longdblsize}\n"; # Ans 8 16
```

I also used this code to try to understand the types, but it didn't help much. Has anyone used it to explain problems like this?

```
use Devel::Peek 'Dump';

Dump ($dSum); # Wow, it's complicated
Dump ($f);
```

Comment: uselongdouble will tell whether your perl was compiled using long doubles or not; if it wasn't, you need to recompile perl.  but Math::BigFloat could be useful instead.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3722679/827263

Comment: @ysth: By which I assume you mean `$Config{uselongdouble}` which requires `use Config`

Comment: correct.  re the Dump() output, there's only one native perl floating point type, the NV.  it is normally a double, but $Config{uselongdouble} indicates perl was compiled to have it be a long double.  note that even a long double will have barely enough precision to store your 1234567890.123456789, so you may need to look at Math::BigFloat anyway

Comment: I added BigFloat and it works. Thanks! I also added $f which seems to indicate that I'm only using double. How can I force long double?

Comment: You probably want to update that Perl. You can get a slightly less antiquated version as an [OpenSolaris package](http://www.opencsw.org/packages/perl/), or you can compile one up easily with [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/).  There have been [a lot of upgrades to Math::BigFloat](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Math-BigInt) since 1.44 which shipped with 5.8.4

Comment: This explains why printf didn't work.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426791/how-can-i-printf-a-perl-bignum-without-losing-precision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[bignum](http://metacpan.org/pod/bignum) will overload all operators in the current scope to use arbitrary precision integers and floating point operations.

```
use bignum;

my $f = 123456789.123456789;
print "$f\n";         # 123456789.123456789
print $f + $f, "\n";  # 246913578.246913578
```

Behind the scenes, bignum turns all numeric constants into Math::BigInt and Math::BigNum objects as appropriate.

It's important to note that bignum is lexically scoped and does *not* effect the whole program.  For example...

```
{
    use bignum;
    $f = 123456789.123456789;  # $f is a Math::BigNum object
}

$g = 123456789.123456789;      # $g is a regular NV

print "$f\n";     # 123456789.123456789
print "$g\n";     # 123456789.123457

# This will use Math::BigNum's addition method, but $g has already lost precision.
print $f + $g, "\n";  # 246913578.246913789
```

You can get a bit better performance out of this by using the [Math::BigInt::GMP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::BigInt::GMP) plugin to use the [GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library) for some operations.  You have to install that module first using the normal CPAN install process (you don't need GMP).  Then tell bignum to use GMP.

```
use bignum lib => "GMP";
```

Comment: 'use bignum;' worked great! I found that Math::BigFloat didn't work with it, but I don't need it now. Thanks!

Comment: Beware that bignum is as much as 100 *times* slower than native perl.

Answer (score 3):

Perl has one size of float, and it's called `NV`. The size of an `NV` is decided when Perl is built.

```
$ perl -V:nvsize
nvsize='8';
```

This information is also accessible within a Perl program via the Config module.

```
$ perl -MConfig -E'say $Config{nvsize}'
8
```

The size of `NV` cannot be changed after Perl is built.

You can force Perl to be built to use `long double` floats as follows when when building Perl:

```
sh Configure -Duselongdouble ...
  -or-
perlbrew install -Duselongdouble ...
  -or-
perlbrew install --ld ...
```

If you don't want to rebuild your `perl` or make a new one, you will need to use a module. I recommend [Math::LongDouble](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math::LongDouble) as it provides access to native `long double` floats, and it does so as transparently as possible.

Another option is to use an arbitrary-precision library such as [Math::BigFloat](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math::BigFloat), but that will be slower that necessary if all you need is a `long double`.